# Android finish thread in Service and update UI

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have a little question about threads and services. I have an example which is downloading data over internet in thread which is running in service. The thing that I want to know is how can I detect when my thread is finished (all data is downloaded) and then to invoke service's `onDestroy()` which will update the UI in all activities which I have to do that.

Any suggestions how to do that and is that the right way which I should do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

1. **Detecting Finished Downloads:** If you use a simple Thread and not [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), you need to create a callback which get's called by the thread to notify the service about the finished downloads (eg. `onDownloadsFinished()`).
2. **Communicating with the Activity:** There are many ways to communicate between Services and Activities but I find [binding to a service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) simplest.
   When bound to the service an Activity can register callbacks directly in the service.
3. **Modify UI:** Make sure you use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) when trying to change UI from within the callback because it will be executed async.
4. **Stopping the Service:** As long as the Activity is bound to the Service, it will run. That is not a problem because when there is no thread within executing something it hardly consumes any resources. You only need to call `stopSelf()` within `onDownloadsFinished()` if you use `startService()` to begin the background downloads. Check [service documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) for further informations.

Answer (score 0):

1) use can make use of messenger in order to communicate between activity and service.        2) if your data is stored in some file or database then just send a broadcast receiver which will tell activity that its time to refresh.                                                  3) use interface. but in this case you will have to store object of that interface which even service can use.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly It depends on what kind of web client do you use to download data, this client determine end of incoming data, after that you should call `stopSelf()` method in your `Service` object class than define your actions in `onDestroy()` method's block

Comment: The idea is that I want to get when the thread is finished and to stop my service after that. I don't think that the service will stop running after the thread is finished automatically. I want to do that, but I don't know how

Comment: I'm not doing it, I want to know that

Comment: I'm still not understand, how do you implement your service. If there is intensive work for CPU, like downloading from web, you should create separate `Thread` in your `Service`, which will make this work and `Thread` will be exist untill your `Service` exists, because your `Service` holds the reference on the `Thread` after calling `stopSelf()` `Service` object and all it's inners will be destroyed by GC. It seems like you think that `Service` has `Thread` functionality by default, but this is wrong. `Service` is only essential which can hold thread's functionality, using `Thread` object.

Comment: I know the difference between thread and service. I have simple class which extends `Thread` and I have another class which extends `Service`. So I'm starting my `thread` in `service` class. I want to know how can I stop my service when my thread finish downloading the files and fire the service to stop. That's my problem which I cannot figure it out.

Comment: There is good description in official documentation of how to implement `Thread` inside `Service`, using `Looper` class. Make your `Thread` jsut like there.